# Convergence of the infinite series. (4 problems)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n>0$ ,$a_n \neq 1$

When $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ Converge, judge under 4 series converge or diverge.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (a_n) \tag{1}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n ^{a_n} \tag{2}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_{n^2} \tag{3}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1-a_n} \tag{4}$$

What I do :

**Problem 1**

From $\sum a_n$ Converge, I got $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ and $0<a_n<1$

$0<a_n<1 \Rightarrow 0<\sin (a_n) < a_n < 1$ and this means $\sum \sin (a_n) < \infty$

**Problem 2**

Let $b_n = a_n ^ {a_n}$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n ^ {a_n} = \lim_{x\to0+} x^x = 1 = \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$$

Thus $\sum b_n = \infty$

**Problem 3**

$\sum \vert (-1)^n a_{n^2} \vert = \sum a_{n^2}$ is absolutely convergent (Am I correct?)

**Problem 4**

I don't know how should I do to solve this. I interpreted $\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}$ as sum of geometric seires, but nothing happened.

Comment: When n is big enough, it's obvious that $\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}<2a_n$.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea How can I get that?

Comment: The serie converge, so $a_n$ tend to zero. And then here exists a $N$, $\forall n>N, a_n<\frac{1}{2}$.